# How to prevent scope binding when edit?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I loaded data into a table and am doing edit and delete. I created [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BiMkY8n2G1gTLIGFdaX1?p=preview) to explain my main problem. Please note that this is not the real application code that I'm using.

My edit function looks like this:

```
$scope.edit = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
};
```

The `$scope.user` binds to input control.

My problem is I don't want to change table data same time when I'm edit from input field. How to prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use  `angular.copy` ie

```
  $scope.edit = function(user) {

    angular.copy(user, $scope.user);

  };
```

please see demo http://plnkr.co/edit/n4g5WKojIsOrtAcm3cgR?p=preview

angular.copy Creates a deep copy of source,in that case copy of 'user' so you are going to edit completely different object instead  of object from your users array

Comment: brilliant ! thanks sylwester. that would be my answer could you please explain why is it happening and how it get solve by using angular.copy() ??

Comment: OK never mind here is the reasons for angular.copy()
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vV1CHwr6oDo#t=167